# Connect Tableau Public to SQL View or Access Query

Tags: sql-server, tableau-api

I'm currently using tableau public for a proof of concept for work.  Is it possible for me to connect to a query in Access without having to rewrite the query in Tableau?  Looking further ahead, I'll be writing queries in SQL server and want to connect to them via Tableau server.

Do I always need to write the queries in Tableau?  Is there a way to connect to Access Queries in Tableau public?  Is there a way to connect to SQL Views via SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tableau Public does not support connecting to SQL databases.

Take a look at this link to see what is supported: https://public.tableau.com/s/download

- Microsoft Excel 2007 or later
- Microsoft Windows Azure Marketplace DataMarket
- OData
- Text files － comma separated value (.csv) files
- Statistical Files; SAS (*.sas7bdat), SPSS (*.sav), and R (*.rdata,
  *.rda)
- Web Data Connectors

Comment: Can tableau desktop/server connect to stored procs or views in SQL Databases?

Comment: Yes, you can work with stored procedures. See: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.htm#connect_basic_stored_procedures.html